# Allow screen pinning automatically by bypassing the permission dialog

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I have an app that makes use of screen pinning. The problem is that, as of now, it asks for the user's permission before pinning the app. I do not want it do this - I simply want it to pin the screen without having to get confirmation from the user.

We have physical access to each device the app is to be used on. With this in mind, is there a setting or similar I can change that would disable the pinning message so that the app would pin itself without user permission?

If it's relevant, the device is running on Android 5.0 Lollipop.

Comment: -1 removed, since the question has been edited and thus is no more developer-centric.

Comment: Did you read this document : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#Enterprise?